'RouteHandlerBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithOpenApi'
I am going through this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/azure-sql-dotnet-entity-framework-core-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=visual-studio%2Cservice-connector%2Cportal
Specific snipped that has the issue:
app.MapGet("/Person", (PersonDbContext context) =>
{
    return context.Person.ToList();
})
.WithName("GetPersons")
.WithOpenApi();

app.MapPost("/Person", (Person person, PersonDbContext context) =>
{
    context.Add(person);
    context.SaveChanges();
})
.WithName("CreatePerson")
.WithOpenApi();

I want to connect azure sql server to my project. I started React + .Net project and these are the only changes I've made however I come across this error:
Error (active)  CS1061  'RouteHandlerBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithOpenApi' and no accessible extension method 'WithOpenApi' accepting a first argument of type 'RouteHandlerBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I came across this documentation but it didn't resolve the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=netcore-cli

I had the same issue with that azuresql learn page.
I followed the .NET CLI steps, and to get my console app connecting to my azure sql db I added two nugets, a using and the few swagger lines, from the referenced url:
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
...
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi;
...

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
...

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

good luck
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/openapi?view=aspnetcore-8.0
